# Using iteration to work out powers

Tags: java, iteration

I'm basically trying to rewrite math.pow, I have the following obviously I'm not getting the concept of returning values. What exactly am I doing wrong?

```
public static int power(int x, int n)
{
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    int i,total;
    for(i = 0; i < n-1 ;i++);
    {   
        total = (x * total);
    }
    return total;


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize total to 1.

```
int total = 1;
```

You can just rewrite everything to:

```
public static int power(int x, int n)
{
    int total = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) // i can be declared here directly
    {   
        total = (x * total);
    }
    return total; // total remains 1 if n = 0   
}
```

Comment: Many correct answers for the initialization. I was doing something stupid as well by having a ; right after my for line so it didn't, no one found that error :-).

Comment: i have found and mentioned in my answer because i executed it in my eclipse before posting :)

Comment: @Jeff: I did catch that, as you can see the ";" does not appear in the code I posted. I just didn't think to explicitly mention that you had an extra ";". :)

Comment: @dku.rajkumar Sorry! Didn't read properly. (That is my problem :-().

Answer (score 3):

```
public static int power(int x, int n)
{
    int total = 1; // Initialized total to 1
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {   
        total = x*total;
    }
    return total;


}
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of `i < n-1`  you should use `i <= n-1`  or `i < n`  and `int total=1`. hope it will work.

also remove `;` from the for loop end. rewriting the code

```
public static int power(int x, int n){
        int total=1;
        for(int i = 0;i < n;i++)
            total *= x;
   return total;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable total starts at 0.  So calling `total = x*total` will always be 0.

You need to initialize total to x.

Answer (score 1):

For one, it looks like you meant:

```
if (n == 0) return 1;
```

check the power, not the base number.

You're not initialisign `total` either, using `total = x` would fix things i think.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with log(n) complexity instead of linear. Be careful with overflow though.

```
int pow(int x, int n) {
    int res = 1;
    while(n > 0) {
        if(n % 2 == 1) {
            res = res * x;
        }
        x = x * x;
        n = n / 2;
    }
    return res;
}
```