# Raise to the power of a number (iterative method)

Tags: java

> We wrote a recursive version of `power`, which takes a double `x` and an integer `n` and returns `x^n`. Now write an iterative method to perform the same calculation.

How do I calculate the power of the numbers? My code keeps printing the results over and over again, and I'm not sure why.

```
public class seventhree {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
        int x;
        int n;

        System.out.print("Type in a base:  ");
        x= in.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Type in an exponent: ");
        n= in.nextInt();

        while(n>=2){
            System.out.println((x)*(n));
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since `n` is not changing inside the while loop the condition is always true.

Comment: What you have there is an infinite loop. It will carry on going as long as `n` is at least `2`, and nothing in the loop alters `n`, so it will never end. Also, what you have written is nothing like calculating the power. Also, [fix your indentation](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43706026/edit). There is no reason code should look like that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using iteration to work out powers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689343/using-iteration-to-work-out-powers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `n` is not changes, you have to decrement the n until it will < then 2, and to make the correct result you have to use  :

```
int rs = 1;
while (n > 0) {
    rs *= x;
    n--;
}
System.out.println(rs);
```

---

**Result example**

```
Inputs       Outputs
x = 6        36
n = 2

x = 2        8
n = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this by using `Bit Manipulation` technique which will give you output in `O(log(exponent))` complexity.

Idea is that split the exponent in sum of integers which are `power` of `2`. Then we can use the numbers which are result of `base^1`,`base^2`,`base^4`.... And then at last we can just multiply all of them which has set bits in `binary representation` of exponent which will give us the final answer.

```
long ans=1;

while(n > 0)
{
    if((n&1)!=0)  //Checking if the bit is set or not
        ans*=x;

    x*=x;         //squaring the base
    n=n>>1;       //shifting exponent to check next bit
}
System.out.println(ans);
```

In your code, You don't decrement `n` so It will end up in an infinite loop. So you can make some changes to your code.

```
long ans=1;
while(n>=1)
{
    ans*=x;
    n--;
}
System.out.println(ans);
```